# Take screenshot on MacOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, delphi, firemonkey

With Firemonkey 11.1, I have two employees using MacOS.

The first one

- Mac OS Catalina with laptop 1280x800
- External display 1920x1080

The second one

- Mac OS Monterey with laptop 1440x900
- External display 1920x1080

[image: Workstation]

On the first one I can take screenshot of the screen of the laptop but not the external display. On the second it's the opposite.

I take screenshot like that, and I try some workaround :

```
LImage := CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(FID, RectToCGTrect(ACaptureRect));

if not Assigned(LImage) then
  LImage := CGDisplayCreateImage(FID);

if not Assigned(LImage) then 
begin
  LBounds := CGDisplayBounds(FID);
  LImage := CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(FID, LBounds);
end;

if not Assigned(LImage) then 
begin
  LBounds := CGDisplayBounds(FID);
  LBounds.origin.x := 0;
  LBounds.origin.y := 0;

  LImage := CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(FID, LBounds);
end;
```

**On first workstation :**

First screen

- `FID = 0`
- `ACaptureRect = 0, 0, 1280, 800`
- Screenshot OK with first `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect`

Second screen

- `FID = 1`
- `ACaptureRect = 1280, 0, 1920, 1080`
- `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect` failed
- `CGDisplayCreateImage(1)` failed
- `CGDisplayBounds` failed return 0, 0, 0, 0
- `CGDisplayBounds` #2 failed too

Full desktop (screen 1 + 2)
I can take full desktop screenshot with 0, 0, 3200, 1920

**On second workstation :**

First screen

- `FID = 0`
- `ACaptureRect = 0, 0, 1440, 900`
- `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect` failed
- `CGDisplayCreateImage(0)` failed
- `CGDisplayBounds` failed return 0, 0, **1440, 900**
- `CGDisplayBounds` #2 failed too 0, 0, **1440, 900**

Second screen

- `FID = 1`
- `ACaptureRect = 1440, 0, 1920, 1080`
- Screenshot OK with first `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect`

Full desktop (screen 1 + 2)
It failed as it's base on display 0 that previously failed too.

There is no logic why only laptop screen work on first workstation, and only external display work on second laptop.

Both have app open on the same screen (on the laptop)

The difference, it that on second laptop (on Monterey), even when I can't take laptop screen, `CGDisplayBounds` return the good size.

I'm out of idea and workaround

EDIT : On same laptop of second workstation, but in BigSur version (not Monterey) all working well ! That's insane

Comment: You can take screen shots using AppleScript, which should be more reliable.

Comment: Do both of your users have your application positioned on same screen? If I would have to guess I would say that your first user probably has your application positioned on the laptop screen while second user has your application positioned on external display.

Comment: Good idea but both have application in laptop and not the external display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ptitBoss: Your FID is simple not good, you retrieve it in the wrong way. Use functions like `CGGetOnlineDisplayList`, `CGGetActiveDisplayList`, etc.

Comment: `CGGetOnlineDisplayList` use a `PCGDirectDisplayID` in param but all exemple I can see use a array, how I can do for loop ?

Comment: @ptitboss that another question, I work only on despesperate question :) don't forget to accept this one :)